# all the elements of vector replace by the last object - java

Tags: java, oop, vector

Here I'm trying to add objects to vector and get the elements back from the vector.
Inside the for loop vector gives the details of all 3 object.
but I want to get the object outside the loop. But it gives the third object details only.

```
static Vector<Student> vector = null;
static Student student= null;
public static void AskStudentDetails(){
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    student = new Student();
    vector = new Vector<Student>();

    for(int i=0; i<MAX_STUDENT; i++){               
        System.out.print("Coursework 01 Marks : ");
        student.setCoursework1(input.nextInt());

        vector.addElement(student); //add object to the vector 
        Student mm = vector.elementAt(0);
        System.out.println(mm.getCoursework1());        
    }
    input.close();
    student = vector.elementAt(1);//assign to the object student 
    System.out.println(student.getCoursework1()); // always print only the value of third object
}
```

Student.class
    public class Student implements java.io.Serializable {

```
    private int coursework1;



    public int getCoursework1() {
        return coursework1;
    }
    public void setCoursework1(int coursework1) {
        this.coursework1 = coursework1;
    }
```

}

Comment: You're adding a reference to the same `Student` object each time. Move `student = new Student()` inside the loop - and make it a local variable, ideally... This question is a dupe of many others, but I haven't got the energy to find them now...

Answer (score 2):

Remove `student = new Student();` from its current place and  place it  inside of your for loop.

```
for(int i=0; i<MAX_STUDENT; i++){
    student = new Student();  // Added here     
    System.out.print("Coursework 01 Marks : ");

}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Highly appreciate your support.

Comment: unfortunately I don't have enough reputations vote your answer.

Answer (score 1):

You're creating only 1 `Student` object and you keep adding it to the vector.
Adding an object to the vector does not mean you're instantiating a new object. If you look to your code, you're calling `new Student()` only once, which means you have a single object that you keep referencing from each field of the vector.

This line

```
student.setCoursework1(input.nextInt());
```

keeps assigning values to the `coursework1` property of the same object.

Answer (score 1):

only one object of Student is created which is outside the loop. hence on order to make it work, you have to create an object every time the loop runs.

```
for(int i=0; i<you_length; i++){
student = new Student(); //this is what you have to add. every time a new object is created.
System.out.print("etc");
}
```